# HttpGet with HTTPS : SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient

Using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/), I receive the following error when attempting to communicate over HTTPS:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated.

Here is my code:

```
URI loginUri = new URI("https://myUrl.asp");

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet( loginUri );
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httpget );
```

How do I suppress or remove this error?

Comment: JDK version? HttpClient version? Also, if you could provide the full stack trace and the URL (is it a public website or not, are you using a self-signed certificate or not), it might help.

Comment: It's a self signed cert. I linked to the version of HttpClient I'm using (4.x, whatever's stable), and I'm using Java 6. I need to ignore this error and perform the get REGARDLESS of the site I'm connecting to.

Comment: Readers might be interested in this related question: [Self Signed SSL acceptance Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217141/self-signed-ssl-acceptance-android)

Comment: Note that it would be best to create a specific `KeyStore` or a `TrustManager` to connect to a specific server that is not verified by one of the pre-installed root certificates, or to create self signed certificates and use those. If you just skip over the problem, then your SSL connection is not secure anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using HttpClient 3.x, you need to do this:

```
Protocol easyHttps = new Protocol("https", new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory(), 443);
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", easyHttps);
```

An implementation of EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory can be found [here](http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/javadocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory.html).

Comment: Updated URL. All you really need to do is google `EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory`. The exact string is so specific that it seemed like there were no bad results.

Comment: It should be noted that this method does exactly what the question asks for: it supresses the error message. It doesn't actually solve the problem since the connection is insecure. The right way would be to import the remote certificate explictly in your trust store.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, and the link leads to a parked page :/

Answer (score 17):

Note: Do not do this in production code, use http instead, or the actual self signed public key as suggested above.

On HttpClient 4.xx:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.junit.Test;

public class HttpClientTrustingAllCertsTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldAcceptUnsafeCerts() throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = httpClientTrustingAllSSLCerts();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://host_with_self_signed_cert");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httpGet );
        assertEquals("HTTP/1.1 200 OK", response.getStatusLine().toString());
    }

    private DefaultHttpClient httpClientTrustingAllSSLCerts() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, getTrustingManager(), new java.security.SecureRandom());

        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(sc);
        Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory);
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);
        return httpclient;
    }

    private TrustManager[] getTrustingManager() {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                // Do nothing
            }

        } };
        return trustAllCerts;
    }
}
```

Comment: And again, for anybody that is interested in security, this does not fix the underlying problem. Import the certificate in your certificate store, but don't trust all connections as you might as well not use SSL.

Comment: Of course. Doing the above in production code would be incredibly counter productive. But if you don't care about security, for example in an end-to-end test against a development server, it's nice to not depend on the server certs.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it never hurts to make that kind of security warning explicit.

Comment: @owlstead "you might as well not use SSL" I use SSL only for encryption, not for authenticating the server to the client, how is this not safe?

Comment: I assume your purpose for using encryption is preventing man-in-the-middle to read your data. If so, without authenticating the cert, you don't know who is at the other end, it could be the man-in-the-middle proxying the communication, i.e. decrypting it, reading it, encrypting it, passing it on. You'll never know...

Answer (score 17):

This answer follows on to [owlstead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/owlstead) and [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat)'s responses. It applies to SE/EE installations, not ME/mobile/Android SSL.

Since no one has yet mentioned it, I'll mention the "production way" to fix this:
Follow the steps from the [AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory class in HttpClient](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/contrib/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java) to update your trust store & key stores.

1. Import a trusted certificate and generate a truststore file

`keytool -import -alias "my server cert" -file server.crt -keystore my.truststore`

2. Generate a new key (use the same password as the truststore)

`keytool -genkey -v -alias "my client key" -validity 365 -keystore my.keystore`

3. Issue a certificate signing request (CSR)

`keytool -certreq -alias "my client key" -file mycertreq.csr -keystore my.keystore`

4. (self-sign or get your cert signed)
5. Import the trusted CA root certificate

`keytool -import -alias "my trusted ca" -file caroot.crt -keystore my.keystore`

6. Import the PKCS#7 file containg the complete certificate chain

`keytool -import -alias "my client key" -file mycert.p7 -keystore my.keystore`

7. Verify the resultant keystore file's contents

`keytool -list -v -keystore my.keystore`

If you don't have a server certificate, generate one in JKS format, then export it as a CRT file. [Source: keytool documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cpjv/index.html)

```
keytool -genkey -alias server-alias -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit
    -storepass changeit -keystore my.keystore

keytool -export -alias server-alias -storepass changeit
    -file server.crt -keystore my.keystore
```

Comment: It's worth noting that steps 2-7 are only required if you need to implement client authentication, too (i.e., letting the server authenticate the client).  In most cases, step 1 alone will be enough.

Comment: how do i create the server.crt?

Comment: Edited to include server.crt creation steps.

Answer (score 4):

This exception will come in case your server is based on JDK 7 and your client is on JDK 6 and using SSL certificates. In JDK 7 sslv2hello message handshaking is disabled by default while in JDK 6 sslv2hello message handshaking is enabled. For this reason when your client trying to connect server then a sslv2hello message will be sent towards server and due to sslv2hello message disable you will get this exception. To solve this either you have to move your client to JDK 7 or you have to use 6u91 version of JDK. But to get this version of JDK you have to get the

Answer (score 0):

Method returning a "secureClient" (in a Java 7 environnement - NetBeans IDE and GlassFish Server: port https by default 3920 ), hope this could help :

```
public DefaultHttpClient secureClient() {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    SSLSocketFactory sf;

    KeyStore trustStore;
    FileInputStream trustStream = null;
    File truststoreFile;
    // java.security.cert.PKIXParameters for the trustStore
    PKIXParameters pkixParamsTrust;

    KeyStore keyStore;
    FileInputStream keyStream = null;
    File keystoreFile;
    // java.security.cert.PKIXParameters for the keyStore
    PKIXParameters pkixParamsKey;

    try {
        trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        truststoreFile = new File(TRUSTSTORE_FILE);
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystoreFile = new File(KEYSTORE_FILE);
        try {
            trustStream = new FileInputStream(truststoreFile);
            keyStream = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ApacheHttpRestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            trustStore.load(trustStream, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
            keyStore.load(keyStream, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ApacheHttpRestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (CertificateException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ApacheHttpRestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            pkixParamsTrust = new PKIXParameters(trustStore);
            // accepts Server certificate generated with keytool and (auto) signed by SUN
            pkixParamsTrust.setPolicyQualifiersRejected(false);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ApacheHttpRestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            pkixParamsKey = new PKIXParameters(keyStore);
            // accepts Client certificate generated with keytool and (auto) signed by SUN
            pkixParamsKey.setPolicyQualifiersRejected(false);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ApacheHttpRestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            ClientConnectionManager manager = httpclient.getConnectionManager();
            manager.getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", 3920, sf));
        } catch (KeyManagementException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ApacheHttpRestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ApacheHttpRestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ApacheHttpRestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (KeyStoreException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ApacheHttpRestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    // use the httpclient for any httpRequest
    return httpclient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your local JVM or remote server may not have the required ciphers.  go here

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce8-downloads.html

and download the zip file that contains:
US_export_policy.jar
and 
local_policy.jar

replace the existing files (you need to find the existing path in your JVM).

on a Mac, my path was here.
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security

this worked for me.