# Android https server connection No peer

Tags: android, https

I'm developing android application, which connecting to server via https connection.
I've created my_store.bks file with trusted sertificate and using following code to connect to server :

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_store);
try{ 
  trustStore.load(in,pass.toCharArray());
}
catch(Exception e){
  Log.v("MyLog", "errror reading sert: " + e.toString());
}
finally{
  in.close();
}
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443);
httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);


HttpPost poster = new HttpPost(serverAdress);
UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams,"UTF-8");
poster.setEntity(ent);

HttpResponse responsePost = httpclient.execute(poster);
```

but when I'm executing this code, I've got next error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate  No peer certificate
```

here is some similar problem
[No peer cert. Not sure which route to take](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035171/no-peer-cert-not-sure-which-route-to-take)   but i don't want ignore  SSL certificates.
Does anyone know what it may be? May it be some server error? (server is developing, so may have errors, but in browser it works fine with sert).