# Android SSLPeerUnVerfiedException

Tags: android

am working https webservice and the certificate is self signed, so import this into my project and create bks file for overriding the error , but still i get SSLPeerUnverfiedException . I had also check with following so question [HttpGet with HTTPS : SSLPeerUnverifiedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308774/httpget-with-https-sslpeerunverifiedexception) ,this also not help me

Comment: do you want to bypass the untrusted site ?

Comment: @HelmiB:yes , i have tried all the way like creating custom sslsocketfactory etc

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach by bob lee: http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html
It solved my issue

Comment: I have tried this also , i have import the certificate ,still i get the error.  The certificate contain a series and the last one is expired

Comment: Has your self signed certificate expired? Maybe you should try creating a new certificate.

Comment: can we do anything at client side ,am not handling the server side

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https
By default trusts all certificates, but you should be careful and be sure that the site is safe