# Android location by network provider sometimes fails

Tags: android, ssl, location, certificate

Sometimes with Android 2.3.1 I've problems in getting my location using the network provider.

This is the logcat:

```
I/System.out(  268): [INFO:2069833702]: LogSource: Running flush
I/System.out(  268): [INFO:2069833708]: LogSource: Sending payload [bytes=708]
I/System.out(  268): [SEVERE:2069834375]: LogSource: AsyncHttpRequestImpl.run(): exception thrown : No peer certificate: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException
```

In this case the wifi network is ok, no connections problems, so the problem seems (maybe?) related to google certificates.

Does anyone know what is going on?
Are other ways to debug these sort of errors? Maybe using ssl commands?

Comment: It looks like the same problem as stated here.hope it will help you.
[check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308774/httpget-with-https-sslpeerunverifiedexception)

Comment: Thank you for your answer...in my case I'm dealing with google certs so I think I must fix this problem in a different way. Probably it's something with the system date/time but I'm not sure...