# i having issue all version android.i use http in service handler class. all api call time null response.i have below error

Tags: android, json, web-services, https

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
11-26 15:35:01.919: W/System.err(353):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLNullSession.getPeerCertificates(SSLNullSession.java:104)
11-26 15:35:01.919: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
11-26 15:35:01.919: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388)
11-26 15:35:01.919: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:231)
11-26 15:35:01.919: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.layerProtocol(AbstractPoolEntry.java:302)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.layerProtocol(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:146)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:654)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:370)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at com.praxify.model.CallServer.makeHttpGetRequest(CallServer.java:1515)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308774/httpget-with-https-sslpeerunverifiedexception

Comment: still not solved my problem