# HTTPS with Self-Signed SSL Certificate Issues... Solution or better way?

Tags: android, https, download, self-signed

All I need to do is download some basic text-based and image files from a web server that has a self-signed SSL certificate.

I have been trying to figure out how to use HttpClient to do this, but getting the SSL to work is a nightmare that seems to be way too much trouble for such a simple task.

Is there a better way to perform these file downloads? Perhaps through a WebView or Browser feature?  Reinventing the wheel of making a simple HTTPS GET request is a major pain, and is significantly holding up my development schedule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found two great examples of how to accept self-signed SSL certificates, one each for HttpsURLConnection and HttpClient.

**HttpsURLConnection solution:** [Https Connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android)

**HttpClient solution:** [Self-signed SSL acceptance on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217141/self-signed-ssl-acceptance-android)

Comment: Neither of the two links listed helped me to implement `HttpsUrlConnection` in my Android app.