# Android: Ignoring Self-Signed Cert Errors; Actual Implementation?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

Like so many here, I'm trying to communicate with a site that has a self-signed cert. There are many many classes and code snippets showing how to do this, e.g. [HTTPS GET (SSL) with Android and self-signed server certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761737/https-get-ssl-with-android-and-self-signed-server-certificate), but I can't find any that show how to actually use the classes. I've experimented a great deal, and I'm sure I'm just missing something simple.

To be specific, I am trying to use the classes supplied by "Moss"; the answer with the most votes. I still always get the "Not trusted cert" message. One other person in that topic has also asked for implementation hints, but has not been answered. Thanks for any help.

If I could append this question to that topic, I'd be much happier, but I guess newbies like me can only post new questions (although I've been a fan of SO for over a year).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a similar `SocketFactory` and `X509TrustManager` implementation in some of our projects. In order to bind these classes up to your implementation, all you basically should have to do is hook them up to the `HttpClient` (assuming that's what you're using) used for client-server communication.

We normally have a method to create an `HttpClient` with the mentioned factory and trustmanager. It looks somewhat like this and is loosely based on the link shown in the inline comments.

```
protected HttpClient constructClient() {
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    // use the debug proxy to view internet traffic on the host computer
    if (ABCApplication.isDebuggingProxy()) params.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, new HttpHost(ABCConstants.DEBUG_PROXY_HOST, ABCConstants.DEBUG_PROXY_PORT, "http"));

    // ignore ssl certification (due to signed authority not appearing on android list of permitted authorities)
    // see: http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", new PlainSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", new FakeSocketFactory(), 443)); 
    ClientConnectionManager cm = new SingleClientConnManager(params, registry);

    return new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
}
```

Hope that helps with your implementation.

Comment: It didn't just help, it just worked! It looks about the same as what all the others I tried were doing, but they were adding quite a few more params. They also seemed to favor using ThreadSafeClientConnManager instead of Single. When I have time I'll educate myself on the difference. Thanx!! (If I had rep I'd +1 your answer).