# Dowloading image resources from https with LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp

Tags: android, image, https, android-async-http

I'm using [LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) to download images but when I try it for HTTPS URLs I get no response.
Code:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get(httpsUrlString, new BinaryHttpResponseHandler(allowedContentTypes) {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] fileData) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(fileData, 0, fileData.length);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
});
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could tell us what you've tried. Have you tried overriding onfailure or anything else?

Comment: Check the example on how to accept all certificates: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/288

Comment: Not the best way to accept all certificates, no point in having HTTPS if you do that. You should have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018681/android-tls-connection-and-self-signed-certificate

Comment: Use HttpsURLConnection http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few open source libraries that do asynchronous image loading. They do not only take care of the download, but also caching and multithreading.

All in all, it is much more handy to use this libraries than to try to write all that code on your own. Right now it is only downloading an image, but in the future you may want caching, etc.

I suggest you take a look at [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley), picasso is simpler to use, but volley has a lot more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code can solve your problem

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
trustStore.load(null, null);

MySSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(MySSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

httpClient.setTimeout(30 * 1000);
httpClient.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
```

Answer (score 0):

a little bit late but you can accept all cerificates this way ..

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(true, 80, 443);
```

in your logs you will see this..

AsyncHttpClient﹕ Beware! Using the fix is insecure, as it doesn't verify SSL certificates.