# How to let the user accept a SSL certificate on android

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

When an android user opens a https website with untrusted ssl certificate in a browser, he is asked wheter he wants to trust the certificate or not.

How to implement such behavior in my android app without accepting every certificate (like described here [HTTPS GET (SSL) with Android and self-signed server certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761737/https-get-ssl-with-android-and-self-signed-server-certificate/4008166#4008166) )

In my app I want to get data from a website that is not mine and has a self signed certificate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accepting a certificate for HTTPs on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012497/accepting-a-certificate-for-https-on-android)

Comment: Thanks @Okas . The question is the same but none of the answers tells how a user could be asked to accept/decline the certificate. Half of them describe how to trust every certificate, half of them describe how you could add a single certificate manually to the trust store.