# How to update server self-signed certificate and keep client not change

Tags: android, https

now i have a big trouble, i develop an android app, and we use the self-signed https certificate, but today is expired, so my app cannot use, i want to know there have some method to update server side key, and keep app side key not change? Because the app had been shipped in the store. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761737/https-get-ssl-with-android-and-self-signed-server-certificate

Comment: Just get a normal certificate, you can even get it for free from something like https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: no, not the same, i know how to use self-sigined certificate in android, my problem is the certificate had been expired, so i want to know how to update just only in server side.