# Volley not retrieving images from https server

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to get an image using volley though a https server. Problem is it doesn't retrieve the image but when testing with a http, it works.

```
imageListener = ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.ivAttachment,
R.drawable.bkg_rr_gray, R.drawable.bkg_rr_gray);
imageLoader.get("https://domain.com/path/to/iamge.jpg",imageListener);
```

help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement HttpStack in volley request. Please check the below link

https://github.com/smanikandan14/Volley-demo#integrating-volley-to-your-project

Comment: To note though, I have tried other https images and they work fine. But certain https does not load. I'm just trying to load images. Does it have to be complicated? Just asking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740975/https-with-self-signed-ssl-certificate-issues-solution-or-better-way may be this will help to you. is that your ssl is self signed certificate?