# Android SSL Connection just by calling "https" instead of "http"

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I connected my app via "https" to my server, like the official page says:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html
(just replaced http with https)
My domain has got the ssl certificate, so its not on the server.
It works on android 6 but it does not work on devices running android 5 or lower to get a ssl connection.
Does anyone know how to get my code work on android 5 and lower?
Do I need to implement a special SSLSocketFactory?

Im looking forward to your response.
Thanks:)

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?  Please provide more details when about what doesn't work.  If you are getting exceptions, add the full stack trace.

Comment: 'javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: no peer certificate'

its just a normal HttpClient, on android 6 it works fine, but the same httpClient throws this exception on android 5 devices

Comment: How did you get the SSL certificate?  Is it self generated?

Comment: You might be using a self-signed certificate, which is not authenticated by phone's CA. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#SelfSigned) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740975/https-with-self-signed-ssl-certificate-issues-solution-or-better-way).

Comment: No, it is a SingleDomain Certificate bought at www.strato.de where also my server is hosted.
So I hat just to replace "http" with "https" and the connection was secured, but unfortunately it does not work on android 5 or lower devices.