# SSL not working on Android 2.2 (only in 2.3)

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl, https

I'm getting this on LogCat when httpsURLConnection.getInputStream() is called

> SSL handshake failure: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol
>   error error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad
>   certificate (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1127 0x29eb40:0x00000003)

I have tested it on Andorid 2.3 and it works nicely.

My server requires client authentication! Maybe FROYO does not support this kind of handshake... I don't know...

**I tried using httpclient as well. Fail in every case...**

```
private void process() throws Exception {

    char[] pass = "clientpass".toCharArray();

    InputStream ksStream = getAssets().open("clientKeyStore.bks");
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    keyStore.load(ksStream, pass);
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(keyStore, pass);
    ksStream.close();

    X509TrustManager[] tm = new X509TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }
    } };

    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tm, null);
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    URL url = new URL("https://192.168.2.101:8443/RestTomcat/resources/veiculos/KKK1234");
    HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    br.close();

    Log.e("OUTPUT", sb.toString());
    httpsURLConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Is the failure in the Android Logcat or server log? And what line of code is it failing on exactly?

Comment: @Jakar Updated! I'm getting this on LogCat when httpsURLConnection.getInputStream() is called.

Comment: I think that there is a differance between the trusted CAs. Who signed that certificate?

Comment: @rekire All certificates are self-signed.

Comment: @CelinHC Did you ever find a solution for this one? I am banging my head trying to find the solution. My guess that 2.2 somehow doesn't send a complete Cert Chain, but can't get that confirmed anywhere. If you found the solution already, I would appreciate if you post your own answer and you'll get my vote. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the date, time and timezone settings are correct on the 2.2 device.

Comment: Exactly the same in both devices... Galaxy Tab (Android 2.2) and Nexus S (Android 2.3)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have found the answer, but this seems to be a bug with Android 2.2 not having to analyze the full certificate chain. If you .p12 cert has multiple chain, Android 2.2 doesn't seem to follow the entire chain.

I had the same problem that I asked the question in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538714/android-2-2-ssl-bug-with-client-certificate). I asked our administrator to generate a new client certificate that is directly issued by Root CA without having the Sub CA and afterwards 2.2 will work. It does bring the question of security of having client certificate without Sub CA as intermediary though.

UPDATE: 
Android team confirm that this is an issue in 2.1/2.2. The details are in the [following issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26542)

Comment: In my case i have a self-signed certificate... So am i lost?

Comment: there is other workaround by replacing the original Android Socket implementation with others which I ended up doing since at the end they still want a more secure Sub-CA to root CA chain. The steps are pretty involved but it works (so far). Let me know if you are interested trying it and I could put it up in the answer. I also posted a bug in Android which they confirm that this is an [issue in 2.1/2.2](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26542)