# Anonymous upload to Imgur's API using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, imgur

I let my user select a picture in their gallery, save its `Uri`, set a title and description and wish to upload it anonymously using Imgur's API, with [this endpoint](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image#image-upload) using `Retrofit 2`.

So far, this is what I am doing with no success:

In my `ImgurAPI` interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("image")
Call<BrowseData>  postImage(
        @Header("Authorization") String auth,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
        @Query("image") String image,
        @Query("album") String albumId,
        @Query("type") String type,
        @Query("title") String title,
        @Query("description") String description
);
```

In my API handler:

```
public void uploadImage(Uri fileUri, String image, String album, String type,
                        String title, String description) {
    // create upload service client (retrofit builder and such)
    ImgurAPI service =
            ServiceGenerator.createService(ImgurAPI.class);

    File file = FileUtils.getFile(caller.getActivity(), fileUri);

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse(caller.getActivity().getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                    file
            );

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);

    // finally, execute the request
    Call<BrowseData> call = service.postImage(clientId, body, image, album, type, title, description);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<BrowseData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BrowseData> call,
                               Response<BrowseData> response) {
            Log.v("Upload", "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BrowseData> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

That is called like such on a simple `FAB` click:

```
controller = new ImgurAPIHandler(this);
controller.uploadImage(chosenUri, encodedImage, "AlbumName", "base64", title, desc);
```

But upon executing the request, I get the following error:

> Write error: ssl=0x9c531200: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe

Can somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong? (If you have sufficient information).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x7f70604080: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016109/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-write-error-ssl-0x7f70604080-i-o-error-during-syst)