# Android - HTTP GET SELF SIGNED

Tags: android, http, ssl, get, self-signed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I accept a self-signed certificate with a Java HttpsURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection)

I have set up a HTTP GET.

The code is as follows:

```
public class GetMethodEx {

public String getInternetData() throws Exception{       

        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI("http://www.google.com");
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
                sb.append(l + nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;        
        } finally{
            if (in != null){
                try{
                    in.close();
                    return data;
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

}

The code allows me to retrieve any http websites, that I assume signed certificates.

However, when I try to retrieve a request from my self-signed server. I get no response.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217141/self-signed-ssl-acceptance-android, you could use the answer given.

Enjoy

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/859111/969325

Comment: Thanks for links guys, I am just a little clueless as to how to implement this into my code.

Answer (score 0):

To resume, you could use one of those two answers and this will resolve your problem:

- [Self-signed SSL acceptance on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217141/self-signed-ssl-acceptance-android)
- [How can I use different certificates on specific connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection) (thanks to Warpzit )

It is easy to fix your problem.

Comment: Do i create a new class for this? or the GetMethod class will be fine?

Comment: You can use the GetMethod class if you need to connect to your non signed server only in this class. The best solution will be to creste a separate class and use it anywhere in your code withoud duplicating code, that's the one of the "good programming techniaues".

Comment: Would I call it before I run the HttpGet or onCreate?

Comment: Which solution are you trying to use?

Comment: If you use the one which is checked as the right answer, you will have to download the two exta classes, as describet. Then, in your GetMethodEx, you will be able to call those methods.

Comment: I am using android 4.0 so, i do not believe this method works. So how will i do Wazrpzit's method?

Comment: Why do you think that with Andorid 4.0 it will not work?

Comment: He mentions this below the code.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, haven't seen that. Check this for froyo and later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899079/custom-ssl-handling-stopped-working-on-android-2-2-froyo

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how to make this work (teen developer) Can you explain please with an answer?