# Android Verify SSL sertificate

Tags: android, ssl, https

I have a little problem with SSL Validation in my application. As I find over internet in FourSquare's documentation they suggest validation like this : [SSL Calidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135679/android-httpclient-hostname-in-certificate-didnt-match-example-com-ex), but the problem is that I'm using an `HttpsURLConnection` and I want to use that class instead of `DefaultHttpClient` . So when I replace client in   `getTolerantClient` with `HttpsURLConnection` and try to do this it's showing me some errors :

```
    public HttpsURLConnection getTolerantClient() {
    HttpsURLConnection client = new HttpsURLConnection();
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().getScheme("https").getSocketFactory();
    final X509HostnameVerifier delegate = sslSocketFactory.getHostnameVerifier();
    if(!(delegate instanceof MyVerifier)) {
        sslSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(new MyVerifier(delegate));
    }
    return client;
}
```

like :

```
The method getConnectionManager() is undefined for the type HttpsURLConnection
```

&

`The method getHostnameVerifier() is undefined for the type SSLSocketFactory`

So any idea how can I use this in my situation?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This code sample should help you to adapt the `getTolerantClient` method:

```
public URLConnection getTolerantClient(URL url) throws IOException {
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    if (!(conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection)) {
        /* not an https:// URL, nothing to do */
        return conn;
    }
    HttpsURLConnection httpsconn = (HttpsURLConnection)conn;
    final HostnameVerifier delegate = httpsconn.getHostnameVerifier();
    if(!(delegate instanceof MyVerifier)) {
        httpsconn.setHostnameVerifier(new MyVerifier(delegate));
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Of course, `MyVerifier` should implement the `javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier` interface.