# The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments [HTTPClient]

Tags: java, imgur, java-http-client

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.omg.DynamicAny.NameValuePair;

public class Upload {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println(Imgur("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\image.jpg",     "clientID"));
    }

public static String Imgur (String imageDir, String clientID) {
    //create needed strings
    String address = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";

    //Create HTTPClient and post
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(address);

    //create base64 image
    BufferedImage image = null;
    File file = new File(imageDir);

    try {
        //read image
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", byteArray);
        byte[] byteImage = byteArray.toByteArray();
        String dataImage = new Base64().encodeAsString(byteImage);

        //add header
        post.addHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID" + clientID);
        //add image
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", dataImage));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        //execute
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        //read response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new         InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String all = null;

        //loop through response
        while (rd.readLine() != null) {
            all = all + " : " + rd.readLine(); 
        }

        return all;

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return "error: " + e.toString();
    }
}
}
```

So I have that code and I got it from [uploading to Imgur v3 using Java https errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710247/uploading-to-imgur-v3-using-java-https-errors) and I get an error on line 50 for "List" telling me

> The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

What can I do to solve this?

I'm using http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/ and want to upload an image to imgur using their v3 API.

EDIT: After changing the import I now get these errors.

That solves that but give me two more errors.

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", dataImage));
```

> The method add(NameValuePair) in the type List<NameValuePair> is not applicable for the arguments (BasicNameValuePair)

And

`post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));`

> The constructor UrlEncodedFormEntity(List) is undefined

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Your import has a subtle error:

> ```
> import java.awt.List;
> ```

It should be:

```
import java.util.List;
```

The problem is that both `awt` and Java's util package provide a class called `List`. The former is a display element, the latter is a generic type used with collections. Furthermore, `java.util.ArrayList` extends `java.util.List`, *not* `java.awt.List` so if it wasn't for the generics, it would have still been a problem.

**Edit:** (to address further questions given by OP) As an answer to your comment, it seems that there is *anther* subtle import issue.

```
import org.omg.DynamicAny.NameValuePair;
```

should be

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair
```

`nameValuePairs` now uses the correct generic type parameter, the generic argument for `new UrlEncodedFormEntity`, which is `List<? extends NameValuePair>`, becomes valid, since *your* NameValuePair is now the same as *their* NameValuePair. Before, `org.omg.DynamicAny.NameValuePair` did not extend `org.apache.http.NameValuePair` and the shortened type name `NameValuePair` evaluated to `org.omg...` in your file, but `org.apache...` in their code.

Comment: How come when I run the program it returns "null : null" or should I post this in a new question?

Comment: @user2526311 Don't set it as null in the beginning, Set it to a dummy or empty string.

Comment: Changed it to 'String all = "";' and it gave me " : null" as a return.

Comment: You seem to have some issue with the buffered reader and the request-respondse. I'd ask a new question.

Comment: Wow, Great but why eclipse imports `java.awt.List` not `java.utils.List`?

Comment: @ehsan First, it's `java.util.List`, not `utils`. Second, the reason for this is because `java.awt.List` is also an available class, just used for something else.

Comment: Thanks that fix my issue ,but may I know why Eclips has imported the wrong library ? is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna Because `java.awt.List` *is* a valid library, that has other uses. Eclipse can't psychically predict which you want.

Comment: I had a similar error - The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>. But this totally fixed my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Try to import

```
java.util.List;
```

instead of

```
java.awt.List;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `java.util.list` will resolve your problem because List interface which you are trying to use is part of `java.util.list` package.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but when i did as below, it resolved the issue.
Instead of writing like this:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
```

use the below one:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
```

Comment: You both used a wrong import. You need the interface for `List` from `java.util.List`.