# Using webElement(Selenium) get all 'x'-tags content as a list

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I get a webElement with:

```
WebElement myElement = browser.findElement(By.cssSelector(".nd_list"));
```

Html of element is something like:

```
<div class="nd_list">
  <div>etc</div>
  <table>
    <span>2</span>
  </table>

  <table>
    <span>3</span>
  </table>
</div>
```

The web element have more html-body, is just for make aa view...The idea is that I want something dynamic. I want to get all `<span>` elements from `myElement` and put their content into an array of int.
Expected result: `int [] myArray = {2,3}`
How can I do that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a CSS selector that gets all `SPAN` children of the `.nd_list` `DIV` you referred to. It's as simple as looping through that collection, getting the text from each element using `.getText()`, and then converting the `String` to an `int`. I tested the code below on your HTML and it worked.

```
List<WebElement> spans = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".nd_list span"));
int[] numbers = new int[spans.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < spans.size(); i++)
{
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(spans.get(i).getText());
    System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebElement>

 at MGbot.Mgbot.main(Mgbot.java:27)

Comment: @Florin One of your imports must be incorrect or there's a copy/paste error. I've run the code on your HTML sample and it works.

Comment: solved it with this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385961/the-type-list-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments-httpcli TY!

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @DebanjanB so what's wrong with my answer since you downvoted it? I explained how to fix the issue and provided code that I tested and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To get all `<span>` elements from *myElement* and put their content into an *integer array* and print them you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> myElement = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".nd_list table > span"));
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(WebElement ele:myElement)
    myList.add(Integer.parseInt(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML")));
Integer[] myArray = myList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
System.out.println(myArray);
```

Comment: OP asked for array of `int` and your code doesn't compile. You can't add `String` to a `List` of `WebElement`.

Comment: That's still a `List` of `int` and not an array.

Comment: @JeffC I have corrected my code, can you revoke your downvote please?

Comment: Are you holding the downvote on my answer hostage? I downvoted because the answer was wrong before the edits and even after the edits it's still inefficient. You are creating a `List` only to turn around and convert it to an array. There's no point in doing that. Also, the print doesn't print the elements... it prints `[Ljava.lang.Integer;@6150c3ec`.