# Client Certificate not working from Android - How to debug?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle, spongycastle

I'm trying to implement a Client Certificates communication for an Android App, so far without much success - and it seems that this feature is, if at all possible, very hard. The full flow I'm implementing is described in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406266/creating-an-https-connecion-with-client-side-certificate-from-pkcs10-with-spong).

I followed the code there and code from [this blog post](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/https-with-client-certificates-on/), describing the same scenario, more or less, without results.

**What doesn't work:** Opening an SSL Connection (`HttpsURLConnection`) between the Android Client and the Server causes the server to return an [403 status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).
AFAIK, this 403 is because the server doesn't get or doesn't trust the Client Certificate that it gets, and I'm not sure how to debug it.

**What does work:**

- Creating a PKCS#10 request, sending it to the CA and getting a signed PKCS#7 (*P7B*)
- Storing the received *P7B* with the private key in a KeyStore, and exporting it to a PKCS#12 (*P12*)
- (**Most annonying**) picking the *P12* from the device, installing it on windows, contacting the server and getting a coherent (200 HTTP-OK) response.

**What I've changed**: From the code samples I got (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406266/creating-an-https-connecion-with-client-side-certificate-from-pkcs10-with-spong) and [here](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/https-with-client-certificates-on/)), I had to change a few things. I'm using HttpsURLConnection and not OkHttpClient as @Than used there (but it shouldn't matter), I can't provide the Certificates as Rich Freedman did (he *had* the certificate, and I'm obtaining it via PKCS#10 and #7), so I've created a CustomTrustManager that would trust the server's certificate, and for this reason I use SpongyCastle (v1.5.0.0 if it matters, set as a provider inserted at 0) and also don't persist the certificate, but all is done in-memory.

**Question is** what to do next:

- How can I tell what the server is expecting (client-certificate wise)?
- How can I tell which client certificates (if any) is being sent to the server?
- How to debug this scenario in general? (Proxies such as Fiddler are useless for the underlying SSL)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not good answer, but there is too much in here to post it as comment.

For logging, debugging you can create your own `X509KeyManager` which uses normal key manager obtained from `KeyManagerFactory`:

`@DebugLog` annotation comes from Hugo library created by Jake Wharton. It prints function arguments and what it return. You can use normal Log.d or whatever you want.

ex:

```
class MyKeyManager implements X509KeyManager {

    private final X509KeyManager keyManager;

    MyKeyManager(X509KeyManager keyManager) {
        this.keyManager = keyManager;
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    public String chooseClientAlias(String[] strings, Principal[] principals, Socket socket) {
        return this.keyManager.chooseClientAlias(strings, principals, socket);
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    public String chooseServerAlias(String s, Principal[] principals, Socket socket) {
        return keyManager.chooseServerAlias(s, principals, socket);
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String s) {
        return keyManager.getCertificateChain(s);
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    public String[] getClientAliases(String s, Principal[] principals) {
        return keyManager.getClientAliases(s, principals);
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    public String[] getServerAliases(String s, Principal[] principals) {
        return keyManager.getServerAliases(s, principals);
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String s) {
        return keyManager.getPrivateKey(s);
    }
}
```

And use it to init `SSLContext`

```
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keyStore, password);

final X509KeyManager origKm = (X509KeyManager) kmf.getKeyManagers()[0];
X509KeyManager km = new MyKeyManager(origKm);

SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslCtx.init(new KeyManager[]{km}, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

You will see which method are called, what are the arguments (obtained from serwer certificate) and which certificate and private key your keymanager returns.