# Error obtaining access token for twitter in android application

Tags: android, authentication, twitter

**I got the following error in my logcat while trying to authenticate my android application with Twitter**

**Besides the username and password are correct for twitter, the message box shows error as'We are unable to log you into Twitter. Please try again later.'**

```
10-24 12:28:24.433: INFO/TwitterService#showProgressDialog(3167): Activity Class Name: com.ap.ui.ArticleActivity
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167): Error obtaining access token for Twitter.
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[e07c50ee-0000d883 1ac06e3f-626a12a6 1ac06e3f-626a127b 1ac06e3f-626a127b 1ac06e3f-626a127b], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.4-SNAPSHOT(build: d2ffce58eec309979a5286d29990e468b0e04942)}
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at twitter4j.http.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:185)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at twitter4j.TwitterOAuthSupportBaseImpl.getOAuthAccessToken(TwitterOAuthSupportBaseImpl.java:108)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at twitter4j.Twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(Twitter.java:54)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at com.ap.service.social.TwitterService.login(TwitterService.java:51)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at com.ap.widgets.twitter.TwitterAccountDialog$LoginRunnable.run(TwitterAccountDialog.java:156)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167): Caused by: TwitterException{exceptionCode=[1ac06e3f-626a12a6 1ac06e3f-626a127b 1ac06e3f-626a127b 1ac06e3f-626a127b], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.4-SNAPSHOT(build: d2ffce58eec309979a5286d29990e468b0e04942)}
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:323)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:72)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:103)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at twitter4j.http.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:178)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     ... 5 more
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:360)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.getSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:168)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnection$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:398)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.sendRequest(HttpURLConnection.java:1224)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doRequestInternal(HttpURLConnection.java:1558)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doRequest(HttpURLConnection.java:1551)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1145)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnection.java:262)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:280)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     ... 8 more
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:168)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:355)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     ... 16 more
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:149)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:211)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:164)
10-24 12:28:25.089: ERROR/TwitterService#login(3167):     ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the device's time / date is set correctly.

Comment: **The device has current date and time**

Answer (score 0):

No this problem is not related to date and time  plz check here
[Self-signed SSL acceptance on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217141/self-signed-ssl-acceptance-android)

Twitter is not allowed on your network(It may be restricted). Switch your network b/w wifi or edge .