# https file download in android causing exception

Tags: android, https

I have a servlet where I am trying to write a file to the response outputstream.

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
String value = "attachment;filename=\"" + appName + "\"";
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", value);
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
response.setBufferSize(99999);
while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    sumBytes = sumBytes + length;
os.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
os.flush();
fis.close();
```

This is working fine for http, but when I try to download the same file over https there is a SocketException.

I think the https connections is getting closed just after the request.

Plase provide a solution for this.

Here is the exception.

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:369)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:439)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:354)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:392)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:381)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
        at com.mfino.appselector.DownloadApp.writeFile(DownloadApp.java:139)
        at com.mfino.appselector.DownloadApp.doGet(DownloadApp.java:101)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:297)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:286)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:743)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:731)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:760)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:359)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:784)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:118)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:593)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:560)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:364)
```

Comment: in the https server, is the certificate a valid signed by a third party one or is it self signed?

Comment: You need to tell the socket to accept that self signed certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, post logcat message.
Meanwhile just blind shot, you've got self-signed certificate.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217141/self-signed-ssl-acceptance-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https).

Comment: I have posted the exception.I think the download is defaulting to http, but there is no socket open over http.

Comment: I've never got such an exception. Maybe try to change buffer size to smaller value, let say 1024 or check if that error occurs with smaller file.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are downloading the data inside the UI thread, please do it in other thread or AsyncTask

Comment: There is no UI involved here. I am hosting an android app in tomcat, and when I identify that the request is from android , I am reading the file from disk and writing to the stream.