# How to use X509 certificates for POST request over HttpsURLConnection?

Tags: java, post, ssl, https

I have

1. A self-signed server certificate (from a third-party organization I need to communicate with)
2. My client certificate, containing the secret key, signed by this server certificate.

Now I need to send a POST request via HTTPS using these certificates.
I managed to test the connection over https in Internet Explorer after I installed them in browser:

1. server cert - into the trusted CA
2. client cert - into the personal certs.

In java until now I used the code, given in [SO: Java client certificates over HTTPS/SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875467/java-client-certificates-over-https-ssl#answer-876785) in the answer by *neu242*, i.e. accepted any certificate. But now the server side does accept this, i.e. I get SSL-handshake failure.

Thanks to [SO: X509TrustManager Override without allowing ALL certs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857417/x509trustmanager-override-without-allowing-all-certs) I tried to return the server certificate in `getAcceptedIssuers`, but in vain. It throws

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

right after `getAcceptedIssuers` returns.

```
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    try {
        X509Certificate scert;
        try (InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("..\\server.crt")) {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            scert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
        }                        
        return new X509Certificate[]{scert};
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        writeLogFile(ex.getMessage());
        return new X509Certificate[]{};
    }
}
```

I guess I should specify the client certificate somehow, but cannot find any way to.
I may be wrong of course.

Hope someone can lead me the right direction.

Comment: Is the handshake failing at client end or at server end? Can you run both your server and client with additional jvm argument `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and share the console output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to make it work.

As the server certificate is self-signed, I had to place it into a truststore. To avoid adding it to common JRE cacerts, I placed it into a truststore in a separate file with the following command (thanks to [Common SSL issues in Java](http://www.javanna.net/2011/07/common-ssl-issues-in-java/):

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts 
        -file servercert.crt -keystore server.jks 
        -keypass mypwd -storepass mypwd
```

Then I used the obtained truststore and the client certificate containing the secret key to initialize key stores and specify them to the SSL context (thanks to [sql.ru: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1051870/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure)):

```
String pwd = "mypwd";
InputStream keyStoreUrl = new FileInputStream("client.p12");
InputStream trustStoreUrl = new FileInputStream("server.jks");

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(keyStoreUrl, pwd.toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = 
    KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, pwd.toCharArray());

KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
trustStore.load(trustStoreUrl, pwd.toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = 
    TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), 
                trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), 
                new SecureRandom());
SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
```

Also I had to specify `HostnameVerifier`, as there were some inconsistency with the server certificate and this server's url:

```
HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        //...
    }
};

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
```

And that is it. Further on it was as simple as:

```
url = new URL(targetURL);

connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();            
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                              "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
                              Integer.toString(Data.getBytes("utf8").length));
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

connection.getOutputStream().write(Data.getBytes("utf8"));
// read response...
```