# DefaultHttpClient get ssl exception on HTTP request

Tags: android, ssl, httprequest

Our android app is referring to `HTTP URL` to get some data from server. It was working properly  till 2 days ago but suddenly we get `"sslpeerunverifiedexception: no peer certificate" exception` while no changes happen neither in our code nor in server. The code is quite simple:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 12000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 12000);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://site.com");
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: please provide logcat details.

Comment: 1) URL is with http or https? 2) Localhost or live url?

Comment: I guess your urls have changed to https, for this you need to add peer certificate and set hostname verifier etc.!

Comment: Androis is 4.1.1 on Galaxy Note II. the URL is live and HTTP only. By browser checking the URL is working just like before

Answer (score 1):

Add below function in your code.

```
public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

And Use below code for call above function.

```
HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();
```

Comment: I tried code similar to this, to ignore SSL exception but I got eclipse error on "SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER" cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @kazemipouya which is your targeted sdk and min sdk?

Comment: min and target in order 14, 16.

Comment: @kazemipouya change your min target sdk to 8 and then build project and then check.

Comment: I'm using Holo as theme and the min target I needed is 13, by the way the problem solved by changing wifi router, I still don't know why but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the server you're accessing is using a self-signed SSL certificate.

While not recommended (could be a MiM attack) you can just ignore this. See this post for more info: [Self-signed SSL acceptance on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217141/self-signed-ssl-acceptance-android)