# Android : HTTPS Connection to my database

Tags: php, android, mysql, ssl, https

I Used to make my connection to php for mysql with HTTP, Now I am asked to Use HTTPS as it is more secure. but i tried to many ways but can't get the tablet to POST or GET any information, I made a self signed certificate and added to Local Computer trusted zone so i wont be asked that its is not verified do i want to continue, i tried connecting by browser and it worked fine and printed all the info that i needed, but not through the app. i attached my Previous HTTP code that i need to change to HTTPS. would like some help to change this connection to HTTPS.

```
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpPost ("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/E-MENU/login.php");        
        username = etUser.getText().toString();
        password = etPass.getText().toString();
        password = md5(SHA1(password));

    try{
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
        entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity!= null){

    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject (convertStreamToString(instream));
```

thanks Upfront.

Answer (score 1):

So it works when you use HTTP but not HTTPS? The problem will be caused by the self-signed certificate on the server not being trusted by Android.

See the accepted answer for this question: [Self-signed SSL acceptance on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217141/self-signed-ssl-acceptance-android)

Comment: Actually I am not sure how to convert my connection "change my http connection" to HTTPS. dont know the code for HTTPS connection setup