# How to do an HTTPS POST from Android?

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, httpsurlconnection

I want to do a HTTPS post method to send some data from my android app to my  website.

I used `HttpURLConnection` first and it's working fine with my HTTP URL. My production website is on HTTPS and I want to send the same POST using `HttpsURLConnection`. Can someone help me use the class properly?

I found some source at [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html):

```
KeyStore keyStore = ...;    
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");    
tmf.init(keyStore);

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");   
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/");   
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)
url.openConnection();   
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());   
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

What should be the value of  `KeyStore keyStore = ...;`?

I tried sending the data using the same  `HttpURLConnection`, but I am seeing some POST data is missed or in error.

I've tried the method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218022/android-https-post-to-bitbucket-issue-tracker-returns-filenotfoundexception?rq=1). I am pasting my code below

```
String urlParameters="dateTime=" + URLEncoder.encode(dateTime,"UTF-8")+
    "&mobileNum="+URLEncoder.encode(mobileNum,"UTF-8");

URL url = new URL(myurl);
HttpsURLConnection conn;
conn=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

// Create the SSL connection
SSLContext sc;
sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
conn.setConnectTimeout(HTTP_CONNECT_TIME_OUT);
conn.setReadTimeout(HTTP_READ_TIME_OUT);

//set the output to true, indicating you are outputting(uploading) POST data
conn.setDoOutput(true);
//once you set the output to true, you don't really need to set the request method to post, but I'm doing it anyway
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(urlParameters.getBytes().length);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
out.print(urlParameters);
out.close();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  response += inputLine;            
}
```

The error I am getting is below:

```
05-12 19:36:10.758: W/System.err(1123): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.myurl.com/fms/test
05-12 19:36:10.758: W/System.err(1123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
05-12 19:36:10.758: W/System.err(1123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:270)
05-12 19:36:10.758: W/System.err(1123):     at .httpRequest(SMSToDBService.java:490)
05-12 19:36:10.758: W/System.err(1123):     at com..access$0(SMSToDBService.java:424)
05-12 19:36:10.758: W/System.err(1123):     at com.$ChildThread$1.handleMessage(SMSToDBService.java:182)
05-12 19:36:10.758: W/System.err(1123):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 19:36:10.758: W/System.err(1123):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
05-12 19:36:10.758: W/System.err(1123):     at com.$ChildThread.run(SMSToDBService.java:303)
```

Comment: share the log and the error you see

Comment: with the above sample code from google, i do not know what to put at the  KeyStore keyStore = ...;

Comment: httpRequest IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  this error is happening for some POST methods, i am using HttpURLConnection with https URL

Comment: if i use HttpsURLConnection  same error i am seeing.. i had not done any of the below codes  KeyStore keyStore = ...; TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509"); tmf.init(keyStore);

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the default CAs that are defined in the android device, which is just fine for any public web.

If you have a self-signed certificate, you can either accept all certificates (risky, open to man-in-the-middle attacks) or create your own `TrustManagerFactory`, which is a bit out of this scope.

Here's some code to use the default CAs for a https POST call:

```
private InputStream getInputStream(String urlStr, String user, String password) throws IOException
{
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Create the SSL connection
    SSLContext sc;
    sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
      
    // Use this if you need SSL authentication
    String userpass = user + ":" + password;
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userpass.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
    
    // set Timeout and method
    conn.setReadTimeout(7000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    
    // Add any data you wish to post here
    
    conn.connect();
    return conn.getInputStream();
}
```

To read the response:

```
String result = new String();
InputStream is = getInputStream(urlStr, user, password);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    result += inputLine;            
}
```

Comment: IOException: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream  this message is coming

Comment: InputStream  inStream = conn.getInputStream();response = inStream.toString();

Comment: I never tried to read an `InputStream` with `toString()`... Added the code I use to read the stream

Comment: The `FileNotFoundException` thrown by the `getInputStream()` happens when the web server returns an error - typically 404 (file not found). This has nothing to do with opening the connection, that worked just fine. Try using FireBug firefox plugin to debug the web server. You can use `getErrorStream()` to read the error message.

Comment: Check your URL is correct and that the server actually accepts a POST operation with that URL.

Comment: how to use the getErrorStream ?

Comment: also i am using Android ICS version for testing

Comment: hi.. i found the problem, there was issue with the SQL query at the web server side.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an [Android HttpsUrlConnection POST solution](https://github.com/echebukati/sec-android-post) complete with certificate pinning, timeouts server side code and configurations.

The variable `params` should be in the form username=demo&password=abc123&.

```
@Override
public String sendHttpRequest(String params) {
    String result = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(KeyPinStore.getInstance().getContext().getSocketFactory()); // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.println(params);
        out.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()), 8192);
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            result = result.concat(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        //} catch (IOException e) {
    } catch (IOException | KeyStoreException | CertificateException | KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        result = e.toString();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Very well. It works for my Lollipop 5.0. Thanks.
What is KeyPinStore ?

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at this question I asked a few days ago:

[Change HTTP post request to HTTPS post request:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389149/change-http-post-request-to-https-post-request)

I have supplied there a solution that worked for me, that basically accepts any self-signed certificate. As been said here this solution is not recommended as it's not secure and open to a man-in-the-middle attacks.

Here is the code:

**EasySSLSocketFactory:**

```
public class EasySSLSocketFactory implements SocketFactory, LayeredSocketFactory {

private SSLContext sslcontext = null;

private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() throws IOException {
    try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new EasyX509TrustManager(null) }, null);
        return context;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private SSLContext getSSLContext() throws IOException {
    if (this.sslcontext == null) {
        this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
    }
    return this.sslcontext;
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#connectSocket(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, int,
 *      java.net.InetAddress, int, org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
 */
public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort,
        HttpParams params) throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
    int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
    int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);
    InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
    SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket) ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket());

    if ((localAddress != null) || (localPort > 0)) {
        // we need to bind explicitly
        if (localPort < 0) {
            localPort = 0; // indicates "any"
        }
        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
        sslsock.bind(isa);
    }

    sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);
    sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
    return sslsock;

}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#createSocket()
 */
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#isSecure(java.net.Socket)
 */
public boolean isSecure(Socket socket) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return true;
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory#createSocket(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, int,
 *      boolean)
 */
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException,
        UnknownHostException {
    return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// javadoc in org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory says :
// Both Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() must be overridden
// for the correct operation of some connection managers
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return ((obj != null) && obj.getClass().equals(EasySSLSocketFactory.class));
}

public int hashCode() {
    return EasySSLSocketFactory.class.hashCode();
}
}
```

**EasyX509TrustManager:**

```
public class EasyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

private X509TrustManager standardTrustManager = null;

/**
 * Constructor for EasyX509TrustManager.
 */
public EasyX509TrustManager(KeyStore keystore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
    super();
    TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    factory.init(keystore);
    TrustManager[] trustmanagers = factory.getTrustManagers();
    if (trustmanagers.length == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("no trust manager found");
    }
    this.standardTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustmanagers[0];
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[],String authType)
 */
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    standardTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certificates, authType);
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[],String authType)
 */
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    if ((certificates != null) && (certificates.length == 1)) {
        certificates[0].checkValidity();
    } else {
        standardTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certificates, authType);
    }
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#getAcceptedIssuers()
 */
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return this.standardTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
}
}
```

**And I added this method: getNewHttpClient()**

```
public static HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

Finally for every place in my code that I had:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

I replace it with:

```
HttpClient client = getNewHttpClient();
```

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated

Comment: MySSLSocketFactory ?