# Is this HTTPS connection secure?

Tags: android, security, ssl, https, httpclient

I was looking for a way to retrive data from a server-side using Https and a self-signed certificate. Following this question:

[Self-signed SSL acceptance on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217141/self-signed-ssl-acceptance-android)

and **@Brian Yarger** Answer I have this:

**EasySSLSocketFactory:**

```
public class EasySSLSocketFactory implements SocketFactory, LayeredSocketFactory {

private SSLContext sslcontext = null;

private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() throws IOException {
    try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new EasyX509TrustManager(null) }, null);
        return context;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private SSLContext getSSLContext() throws IOException {
    if (this.sslcontext == null) {
        this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
    }
    return this.sslcontext;
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#connectSocket(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, int,
 *      java.net.InetAddress, int, org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
 */
public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort,
        HttpParams params) throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
    int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
    int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);
    InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
    SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket) ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket());

    if ((localAddress != null) || (localPort > 0)) {
        // we need to bind explicitly
        if (localPort < 0) {
            localPort = 0; // indicates "any"
        }
        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
        sslsock.bind(isa);
    }

    sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);
    sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
    return sslsock;

}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#createSocket()
 */
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#isSecure(java.net.Socket)
 */
public boolean isSecure(Socket socket) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return true;
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory#createSocket(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, int,
 *      boolean)
 */
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException,
        UnknownHostException {
    return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// javadoc in org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory says :
// Both Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() must be overridden
// for the correct operation of some connection managers
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return ((obj != null) && obj.getClass().equals(EasySSLSocketFactory.class));
}

public int hashCode() {
    return EasySSLSocketFactory.class.hashCode();
}
}
```

**EasyX509TrustManager:**

```
public class EasyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

private X509TrustManager standardTrustManager = null;

/**
 * Constructor for EasyX509TrustManager.
 */
public EasyX509TrustManager(KeyStore keystore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
    super();
    TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    factory.init(keystore);
    TrustManager[] trustmanagers = factory.getTrustManagers();
    if (trustmanagers.length == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("no trust manager found");
    }
    this.standardTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustmanagers[0];
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[],String authType)
 */
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    standardTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certificates, authType);
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[],String authType)
 */
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    if ((certificates != null) && (certificates.length == 1)) {
        certificates[0].checkValidity();
    } else {
        standardTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certificates, authType);
    }
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#getAcceptedIssuers()
 */
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return this.standardTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
}
}
```

**And I added this method: getNewHttpClient()**

```
public static HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

Finally for every place in my code that I had:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

I replace it with:

```
HttpClient client = getNewHttpClient();
```

I'm able now to receive the data from server side.

**The Question:** is what I did is secure? or it's accepts any self-signed certificate? if this is the case what should be done to change it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use a self-signed certificate?

Comment: what do you mean? I have very little experience with https connections. Using this code I'm able to connect and retrieve data from server-side that uses self-sined certificate using https URL.

Comment: I don't get It, why are people down-vote this question and vote to close it. It's a programming question. it's not off-topic.

Comment: I've been banned for (almost) the same reason: I don't know. I can recognize that my questions are not the best and maybe looks like they don't show incredible research effort. You know why? Because I am not an expert and I'm here to ask and learn. But enough about whining... I've learned the lesson and I'm trying my best to get unbanned but this is not easy when incredible people answer to question I could answer in 10 seconds.
You have great score so probably it's useless to say but think 10 times before posting a question here.

Comment: ps of course I could try to answer question experts answer but it would take me a little more than 10 seconds: sorry if I was unclear :)

Comment: @Pitto, I'm not really getting what you are trying to say. You can look in my profile and see that I wrote here enough questions to know how to write a good on topic question. This question is a programming on-topic question regarding secure connection in android platform. People just vote to close it without reading it to earn a reputation in the reviewing section.

Comment: I am sorry if I was unclear... Probably, as said in meta, the questions downvoting and/or closing should require a mandatory comment :) ps I didn't want to mean that you can't write a question I wanted to say that one has to be really extra careful when posting one (and you probably are).

Answer (score 1):

No peer with that trust manager can be possibly secure. All you're doing to check whether a server presenting a self-signed certificate is trusted is to check the validity of the certificate. That is not sufficient. You are open to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: Could you please explain then, what are the steps needed to to make it a secure connection and avoid main-in-the-middle attacks? Code snippet or further reading material would be very welcome as I have no clue in this secure stuff.

Comment: (1) Get rid if that security manager and (2) take *offline* steps to import any trusted self-signed certificates.

Comment: what do you mean by: "(2) take offline steps to import any trusted self-signed certificates", I should import the server certificate directly in my application resource directory and check if they match when I make a call to server side?

Comment: Import the self-signed certificate into the client's truststore. That's it. JSSE will do the rest.

Comment: Ok, I will try to implement it and accept your answer if it works.

Answer (score -1):

You can capture the Packet and check read the packet, If the connection is SECURE then packet will come in encoded format other wise you can get the decoder plugin to read the Packet

Comment: could you please provide some code snippet? as I have no idea how it done.

Comment: This is neither necessary nor sufficient. The question isn't whether it's encrypted. The question is whether it's secure. It's not the same thing. -1.

Comment: @EmilAdz The best way you can do this is to take tcpdumo on the given machine, after taking the dump open this using wireshark and check hopeit helps