# Install self-signed SSL certificate on Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm developing an app for Google Glass, which has to get some data over https from specific servers. These servers host a simple WCF OData service. 
As getting proper root CAs is not always an option, I need a way to install my own self-signed .cer files on the device.

I haven't found anything about this...

https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=125

The link above suggests, that this should work, but I have no idea how...

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Personally, instead of trying to import the SSL cert into Glass, I would include a custom HTTPS handler that verifies the SSL cert, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15531475/220591